# CRUD interface using one controller for many subtypes

Tags: java, jsp, reflection, crud

I am trying to setup a single CRUD controller and relevant views (JSP) to handle several subclasses of the same superclass.  Having a controller/views for each subclass results in a lot of copy/paste code.  My first inclination is to use reflection.

From another page, the user clicks a link that determines the action and the proper subclass to work with.  So in my controller I'll have the service return an instantiation of the proper type, and then for the view, I would like to display and edit all of the field names and values.

Here's what I have so far for my new action:

```
// controller new action code
SubType sub = service.give_me_type(x);
List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();

fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(sub.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields()));
fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(sub.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));

return new ModelAndView("/sub/form")
  .addObject("fields", fields);


// view form.jsp
<form:form method="post" commandName="sub" cssClass="left">
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty fields}">
  <table>
  <c:forEach items="${fields}" var="field">
    <tr>
      <td>${field.name}</td>
      <td>value here</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </table>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
  ...
```

I realize that putting the fields in a List doesn't help with wiring the object to the view, but I'm not sure what to try next.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Spring MVC

Edit: I'm thinking about not trying to wire up the object with the view.  Looking at the edit/update actions as an interesting case, on edit I'll load my List from my object then display that in the view; on create I'll set the values in the object from the values found in the List that were user-entered in the view.  Would that be a descent solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advice to use something like Struts or Spring MVC, because you will hit lots of problems, related to mapping to custom field types, checking fields of super-super-class and granting access to them etc.

http://alasdoo.com/2010/08/binding-data-with-spring-forms/

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using Spring MVC; sorry about that.  I'll put that in the question.

Comment: @Mickey why are you doing it that hard? Why not to use form binding for instance? See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Comment: In that tutorial, I don't see where Student is subclassed.  I am trying to have the controller and its views handle all the derived classes of a base class, and to avoid creating a controller/views for every subclass.